# Integration of One trust in AEM (adobe experience manager) website

Tags: reactjs, aem, one-trust

I followed the steps of one trust(through onetrust documentation) ,

added onetrust javacript script in my home page and auto blocking is enabled.

My react code sets cookies. Once customer logs in both necessary and secondary cookies.
In source it is all just one file.

Now if I select I only want strictly necessary cookies in onetrust then it blocks the js file which has cookies set for necessary flows also.

Please Note: My React code is packaged within AEM

How do others handle onetrust with react apps ?
How can I handle this case ?